# Http Error When Running .NET Core App After Upgrade

Tags: c#, visual-studio, http, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a program that was written in .NET Core 1.0 in an old TFVC repo and I decided it was time to update it to Core 3.1.

So, I first converted the TFVC repo to a GIT repo. All was good. I then followed along with the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to upgrade from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, and so on. Everything seemed pretty straight forward, and I now have a my project updated without any errors in Visual Studio.

My issue is that when I run my app, I get the following error:

```
http error 500.37 - ancm failed to start within startup time limit
```

I have attempted to change the timeout time, but no matter how long I set it to, I always get that error once the timeout is reached. I have also made sure to look into my computer resources when this app is started, and there are no spikes in CPU or memory.

I assume this error was caused somewhere along the lines of upgrading. Does anyone know where I should be looking to solve this? I can add code snippets where required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the start, if  you use IIS,  open Computer Management -> Event Viewer -> Window Logs -> Application and try to get more detail message about the error.